# Simple weighted embedding network

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have several embeddings matrices, lets say E1 matrix is for Glove and E2 is for Word2vec.

I would like to build a simple sentiment classifier which takes trainable weighted sum of this embeddings.

For example, for the word "dog" I would like to get x["dog"]*E1["dog"] + y["dog"]*E2["dog"] when x and y are learned parameters (notice that I want to learn x and y for each word
I know I need to somehow learn the X vector and Y vector and use merge with "add", but I have no idea how to actually do it, help will be highly appreciated.

My network looks as follows:

```py
embd = Sequential()
embd.add(Embedding(topWords + 2, embedding_vecor_length, 
input_length=max_review_len, weights=[embedding_weights],trainable=False))
sent_model = Sequential()
sent_model.add(embd)
sent_model.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, border_mode='valid', 
activation='relu', input_shape=(max_review_len, embedding_vecor_length)))
sent_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while I used keras. But I would do it this way:

Glove and Word2Vec you will probably load using gensim library. I assume you know how to load these into the keras embedding layer. If not, please let me know.

Here you will set the both embedding layers to *non-trainable*.

For *X* and *Y* you can create two other embedding layers like you would do for E1 and E2 without supplying weights and setting them to *trainable*, these will be learned by the network during the training process.

You probably could use also a Dense layer instead, but I think using an embedding layer makes it easier.

For multiplication and adding there is an example how to use it, taken from [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/):

```py
import keras

input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
added = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])  # equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])

out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(added)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=out)
```

**UPDATE:**

> For example, for the word "dog" I would like to get x["dog"]*E1["dog"]
>   + y["dog"]*E2["dog"] when x and y are learned parameters (notice that I want to learn x and y for each word I know I need to somehow learn
>   the X vector and Y vector and use merge with "add", but I have no idea
>   how to actually do it, help will be highly appreciated.

So, I haven't tested this, also because I don't have the data, there may be some mistakes in the code - but in general it should probably look like this:

```py
#input
sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_review_len,), dtype='int32')

# loading your Glove embedding
layer_E1 = Embedding(w1.shape[0],w1.shape[1],
                            weights=[w1],
                            input_length=max_review_len,
                            trainable=False)
# loading your Word2Vec embedding
layer_E2 = Embedding(w2.shape[0],w2.shape[1],
                            weights=[w2],
                            input_length=max_review_len,
                            trainable=False)
# applying embeddings
embedded_E1 = layer_E1(sequence_input)
embedded_E2 = layer_E2(sequence_input)

# creating learnable embedding layer X and Y
layer_X = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_len)
layer_Y = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_len)

# your weights X and Y
embedded_X = layer_X(sequence_input)
embedded_Y = layer_Y(sequence_input)

# Multiplying X*E1 (x["dog"]*E1["dog"])
layer_E1_X = keras.layers.Multiply()([embedded_E1, embedded_X])
# Multiplying Y*E2 (y["dog"]*E2["dog"])
layer_E2_Y = keras.layers.Multiply()([embedded_E2, embedded_Y])

# merging the results with add
added = keras.layers.Add()([layer_E1_X, layer_E2_Y])

# …
# some other layers
# … 

your_final_output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(previous_layer)

model = Model(sequence_input, your_final_output_layer)
model.compile(…)
model.fit(…)
```

*Edit: I forgot to apply the X and Y embedding, I added it now.*

*(Please think of this as a rough idea or outline, you may need to change some things)*

Important here is that the dimensions match, so both embeddings E1 and E2 should have the same embedding dimension. `embedding_vecor_length` must be also the same for this to work.

`w1` and `w2` in the code are assumed to be your glove and word2vec embeddings loaded with gensim.

So, I hope this is roughly what you wanted to do. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort :)
the start of my network for one kind of embeddings is something like:
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(weights=[embedding_weights],
                                   trainable=False))
I am fine with adding my networks untrainable pre-trained embeddings, thanks for asking :)
So, i'm working with "Sequential" and the embeddings probably getting the inputs somehow, if you can help me with writing an trainable vector x with the dim [1, size of vocabulary] that learns a weight for every word this could be very helpful since the rest I can get done

Comment: sorry for deleting my accidentally response, I'm actually still need your help :)

Comment: You should update your question, this helps others with the same problem.
I'm not sure if you can use the sequential model for this kind of network. Because you want the inputs to be fed into E1 and E2 at the same time, I think this might be problematic with the sequential model.
Please add some of the code to your question, I can try to rewrite it without sequential model.

Comment: "you want the inputs to be fed into E1 and E2 at the same time"
actually this can easily be solved with "merge" and I have some code for that, I will prefer to stay with the "sequential" model, if you show me how to do it for one embedding matrix I could easily generalize to few. 
The code was added to the question :)